# CUDA __float_as_int in acosf implementation

Tags: c, math, cuda, ptx

CUDA C's maths function implementation (`cuda/math_function.h`) of `acosf` contains the passage:

```
if (__float_as_int(a) < 0) {
  t1 = CUDART_PI_F - t1;
}
```

where `a` and `t1` are `floats` and `CUDART_PI_F` is a `float` previously set to a numerical value close to the mathematical constant Pi.
I am trying to understand what the conditional (if-clause) is testing for and what would be the C equivalent of it or the function/macro `__float_as_int(a)`. I searched for the implementation of `__float_as_int()` but without success. It seems that `__float_as_int()` is a built-in macro or function to NVIDIA NVCC. Looking at the PTX that NVCC produces out of the above passage:

```
    .reg .u32 %r<4>;
    .reg .f32 %f<46>;
    .reg .pred %p<4>;
    // ...
    mov.b32         %r1, %f1;
    mov.s32         %r2, 0;
    setp.lt.s32     %p2, %r1, %r2;
    selp.f32        %f44, %f43, %f41, %p2;
```

it becomes clear that `__float_as_int()` is not a `float` to `int` rounding. (This would have yielded a `cvt.s32.f32`.) Instead it assigns the `float %f1` as a bit-copy (`b32`) to `%r1` (notice: `%r1` is of type `u32` (unsigned int)!!) and then compares `%r1` as if it was a `s32` (signed int, confusing!!) with `%r2` (who's value is `0`).

To me this looks a little odd. But obviously it is correct.

Can someone explain what's going on and especially explain what `__float_as_int()` is doing in the context of the if-clause testing for being negative (`<0`)? .. and provide a C equivalent of the if-clause and/or `__float_as_int()` marco ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__float_as_int` reinterprets `float` as an `int`. `int` is `<0` when it has most significant bit on. For `float` it also means that the sign bit is on, but it does not exactly mean that number is negative (e.g. it can be 'negative zero'). It can be faster to check then checking if `float` is `< 0.0`.

C function could look like:

```
int __float_as_int(float in) {
     union fi { int i; float f; } conv;
     conv.f = in;
     return conv.i;
}
```

In some other version of this header `__cuda___signbitf` is used instead.

Comment: Interesting! So it's for performance reasons implemented like this.

Comment: Single-precision floating-point comparison is no slower than an integer comparison on the GPU. The earlier use of signbitf() in this if-statement required a bit extraction plus a comparison, however.